# How to remove round up functionality when the value need to be reused in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using roundup function in one column of cells in excel. In the next column of cells, i just need to subtract the values from the previous column. But when I use it in the next cell, I want it to take the cell value or the rounded up value but it is still taking the original value...How to avoid this?

Need some guidance to solve this.

Example:

*I have put here an example. Fix it and delete this line when you're done, leaving the example*

```
            | A      | B            | C
 -----------+--------+--------------+-----------------
 formulas:  |        | =ROUND(A1;3) | =IF(...;A1;B1)
 values:    | 0,5715 | 0,572        | 0,5715
 -----------+--------+--------------+-----------------
```

This is my situation:

Value for first row is =ROUND(O7*1000,1) and value for second row is =J8-J7.

The image is [image]

You can see that in the 3 row 2 column, the value should be 74, but it is 73. How to change this?

Comment: Couldn't you *simulate* the roundup by setting the appropriate number of decimals in the field format? Then you wouldn't need the rounding. Otherwise, you could put the answer in a hidden cell/column, and in the visible one place `=ROUND(hidden_addr)`. You'd be free to use *hidden_addr* in the new column.

Comment: @PortlandRunner I think u are getting it wrong. It is already rounded up. But when I use it in the next cell, I want it to take the cell value or the rounded up value but it is still taking the original value...

Comment: 0.5715 roundsup to 0.571.. it doesn't seem to round up correctly...

Comment: Sorry, then I have misunderstood. What do you mean with "the cell value **or** the rounded up value"? You want the new cell to assume a value *instead of* another, based on some condition? Might then not the error be in the condition itself?

Comment: I've added a sort of an example which you can modify to illustrate what's happening. You can also cut it and paste twice, once with the results you're getting, the other with the results you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=ROUND(O7*1000,1)` but that will give you a number with 1 decimal place.

ie if cell **O7 = 0.5715**, your rounded number will be **571.5**.

Your screenshot shows numbers formatted to omit the decimals, but I suspect that they are there hidden behind your **569, 498, 572...** These additional decimals that then throw out your subtraction `=J8-J7` in the second row.

You want whole numbers so you need to round with zero decimal places:

```
=ROUND(O7*1000,0)
```

**Note:** you do seem to use ROUND() and ROUNDUP() interchangeably in your post - these are two different functions. So you may want `=ROUNDUP(O7*1000,0)`.